# Create Time series observations,timestamps and filling up the values

Tags: r, time-series

I have a cross section data as following:

```
transaction_code <- c('A_111','A_222','A_333')
loan_start_date <- c('2016-01-03','2011-01-08','2013-02-13')
loan_maturity_date <- c('2017-01-03','2013-01-08','2015-02-13')
loan_data <- data.frame(cbind(transaction_code,loan_start_date,loan_maturity_date))
```

Now the dataframe looks like this

```
>loan_data
    transaction_code    loan_start_date    loan_maturity_date
1            A_111      2016-01-03         2017-01-03
2            A_222      2011-01-08         2013-01-08
3            A_333      2013-02-13         2015-02-13
```

Now I want to create a monthly time series observing the time to maturity(in months) for each of the three loans for a period of 48 months. How can I achieve that? The final output should look like following:

```
>loan data
   transaction_code    loan_start_date    loan_maturity_date   feb13  march13 april13........
1            A_111      2016-01-03         2017-01-03          46       45     44
2            A_222      2011-01-08         2013-01-08          NA       NA    NA   
3            A_333      2013-02-13         2015-02-13          23       22      21
```

Here new columns (for 48 months) represents the time to maturity for each loan from that respective months.
Would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify how you'd like to calculate "time to maturity"? I don't understand yet how they relate to `loan_maturity_date`. For instance, the third loan has a later loan maturity date than the 2nd loan (in 2015, vs. 2013), yet smaller numbers in the columns to the right.

Comment: Hi @JonSpring, I just assumed the values. Now I have fixed it. The value for feb13 in the 1st row is the difference in months between 2013-02-28 and 2017-01-03. For march13, its the difference in months between 2013-03-31 and  2017-01-03. And so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tidyverse` packages.

```
# Define the months to use in the right-hand columns.
months <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2013-02-01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)

library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
loan_data2 <- loan_data %>%
  # Make a row for each combination of original data and the `months` list
  crossing(months) %>%
  # Format dates as MonYr and make into an ordered factor
  mutate(month_name = format(months, "%b%y") %>% fct_reorder(months)) %>%
  # Calculate months remaining -- this task is harder than it sounds! This
  #   approach isn't perfect, but it's hard to accomplish more simply, since
  #   months are different lengths. 
  mutate(months_remaining = 
           round(interval(months, loan_maturity_date) / ddays(1) / 30.5 - 1),
         months_remaining = if_else(months_remaining < 0, 
                                    NA_real_, months_remaining)) %>%
  # Drop the Date format of months now that calcs done
  select(-months) %>%
  # Spread into wide format
  spread(month_name, months_remaining)
```

Output

```
loan_data2[,1:6]
#   transaction_code loan_start_date loan_maturity_date Feb13 Mar13 Apr13
# 1            A_111      2016-01-03         2017-01-03    46    45    44
# 2            A_222      2011-01-08         2013-01-08    NA    NA    NA
# 3            A_333      2013-02-13         2015-02-13    23    22    21
```